# What are the different symbols used for denoting an angle?

Tags: soft-question, notation

This is not a question involving numbers and stuff, but suddenly had this basic question in mind: What are the different symbols that different people use for denoting an angle? (I mean, we usually use this $\angle$ symbol for denoting an angle; some people use the one with a c-curve, something like that).

I suddenly had this question as I was going through bunch of question papers of different MO’s in different countries, and just realised that they use different symbols to denote an angle. This may seem to be a very simple and basic question, but I need it because I just know a bunch of symbols in math and knowing more symbols helps me in exams. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to provide more specific examples of the symbols you mean? Really, the ones that I see most often on this site are $\angle$, and $\sphericalangle$ or $\measuredangle$.

Comment: Like C with a cap on it.

Comment: Yup, no doubt, the ones you have mentioned are the most prominent. But these (the C cap) symbols are also used occasionally. So this question came in my mind.

Comment: That’s the problem there,too. When you get accustomed to the usual symbols and suddenly someone introduces this new kind of symbols, especially in exams, they make things worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\angle$ is usually used to denote a standard angle, whereas $\measuredangle$ is used to denote a *directed angle*.

That is, given two non-parallel lines $\ell$ and $m$, the directed angle $\measuredangle(\ell, m)$ denotes the measure of the angle starting from $\ell$ and ending at $m$, measured counterclockwise.

Comment: do you mean these are the only symbols to denote an angle? I saw that $\hat C$ also meant angle C..

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: INMO 2013, more precisely..

Comment: Yes, they use $\hat{C}$ to denote $\angle C$ in Problem 5. It can be figured out from the context of the problem.

Comment: Well, yeah, but is there _any other_ symbol that people use? No, right?

Comment: Usually not, but the writer can use whatever symbol they want, as long as they make it clear to the reader.

Comment: Alright, OK then.